# Tool for convert SQL code to diagram

Tags: sql, mysql, database, entity-relationship

can any one say some way to convert SQL code to data diagram like ERD ? for som DBMS like MySQL or general SQL

Comment: I can't think of a single ERD application that doesn't allow reverse engineering from either a DB or a script. Can you be a little more specific? Do you currently have an ERD application that you're using? What format do you want it in?

Comment: I need a tool convert sql code ( create table ) to diagrams like ERD (ERD not important )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MySQL can use sqlyog :

> SQLyog MySQL GUI is the most powerful
>   MySQL manager and admin tool,
>   combining the features of MySQL Query
>   Browser, Administrator, phpMyAdmin and
>   other MySQL Front Ends and MySQL GUI
>   tools in a single intuitive interface.

http://www.webyog.com/en/

Answer (score 16):

using mysql Workbench do the following:

1- file -> new model

2- file -> import -> reverse engineer mysql create script

select ur mysql file script

and tick on place imported objects on a diagram

and press next and finish

Comment: Thanks man! Worked for me, even with dockerized workbench https://hub.docker.com/r/openkbs/mysql-workbench/

Answer (score 5):

Use MySQL WorkBench. It's perfect and absolutely compatible with MySQL, Oracle powered!

Check it out here: [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 2):

ModelRight, http://www.modelright.com/ , is a good ERD application and is free for MySQL and ODBC connected databases. It reverse engineers from a DB, if you want to reverse engineer from SQL Script, you should check out Dezign for Databases, http://www.datanamic.com/